# wso2 is 5.11.0 adaptive authentication retry page is not coming

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using custom authenticator, if it fails then basic authenticator will be used for login and on login success I am using another authenticator to set the custom claims and after that a forced reset authenticator to check force password reset incase of password expiry.

But if basic authentor fails the page is redirecting to SAML authenticator failure instead of login page with retry option. So,how to retry login incase of failure and incase of success call `Step3` and `Step4`.

```
Step1: custom authenticator
Step2: basic authenticator
Step3: local authenticator
Step4: password reset enforcer


var onLoginRequest = function(context) {
    executeStep(1,{
        onSuccess: function (context) {
        },
        onFail: function(context){
            executeStep(2,{
                onSuccess: function (context) {
                    executeStep(4);
                    executeStep(3);
                    
            },
                onFail: function(context){
                
                }
            });
             
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retry from the authenticator itself is suppressed when you enable the adaptive script. This is to give full control for the adaptive script to write the fallback logic way more than just simple retry. Related discussions can be found at the link [Retry with authenticators for adaptive authentication.](https://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2018-May/077294.html)

You could find samples how to do retry [User's failed login attempts based adaptive authentication](https://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2018-November/078641.html)
. You can do much more than just retry following this way.